# serializing django models (for use in js files)?

Tags: javascript, python, django

-- DJANGO/PYTHON--

```
class Sounds(models.Model):
    sound = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    syl = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0) 

 def as_json(self):
    return dict(
        input_id=self.id, sound=self.sound,
        syl=self.syl, tone=self.tone)
```

--JS--

```
function init()
{
    -- create a list of all instances with tone = 1 --
}
```

This is what my model looks like. In my js file, I want to be able to pull all created instances with a certain tone (or syllable, etc..) into a list so I can use them. I created the as_json function (above), but I'm not sure where to call this function. If I call in in the python file, then..how can I use it in the js file, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide a view (w/ a url) to call to get the Json. There are some examples here:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/27/how-to-return-json-encoded-response.html

and something more concrete:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

In the interests of having something here in this answer, consider this (pseudocode) view:

In 'views.py':

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string   
from .models import Sounds

def sounds_json_detail(request):
    sound = Sounds.objects.get(some_lookup_here)
    context['sound'] = sound.as_json()
    html_sound = render_to_string('sound_detail.html',
                     context,request=request,
                )
    return JsonResponse({'html_sound': html_sound})
```

where the sound_detail.html is a template you need to provide - I do this in ajax calls, but you can omit this if you just want to post your json.